# Slow access to Android files on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: files, android, 18.04, filemanager, transfer

I have a Samsung Galaxy S6 running on Android 7.0, i upgraded my os from 16.04.1 lts to 18.04 lts, and now when i plug my phone on my computer with my usb data cable, i barely can't access it..

When i click on the phone to open the directory, the mouse cursor change to the loading cursor and get stuck on it, i can't change the directory so i'm obliged to quit the File Manager...

I tried searching if somebody had the same issue but didn't find anything, i also tried rebooting, repluging and stuff...

Thanks for your help

Comment: I have the same issue on a different Android phone. Looks like some bug was introduced in 18.04, but I don't know where to start with reporting it.

Comment: @pandasauce i had this problem on ubuntu 17.10 too and not before, so i think it was introduced on ubuntu 17.10

Comment: Same here. transferring files is ok but detecting the phone and storage or opening a folder takes very long time. it may be a driver issue

Comment: I'm having the same issue with a Samsung Galaxy S8 after upgrading from Ubuntu 16 to 18.

Comment: So you guys are saying there is no solution? This is so blocking for me...

Answer (score 0):

Look at this perfect answer: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/91900/is-there-a-viable-alternative-to-mtp-for-file-transfer/106323#106323

It is possible to install an app, which creates a local webserver, which is accessible through the file browser on your computer through USB tethering network.

Comment: It's a shame that on Ubuntu it must be used an external App to simply browse a list of files! It must be a base feature of Ubuntu.

Comment: @user2342558 That's the fault of the MTP protocol, not Ubuntu. You can thank Microsoft and Android for that mess.